# Cordova : how to debug android --prod build

Tags: android, cordova

I have an issue with a cordova application which occurs only when building it with the command : cordova build android --prod --release
When building in debug mode, everything works fine.

I use chrome://inspect to debug my app, but this work only with debug build

How can I inspect and debug my app when building for production ?

Edit: no solution, this seem to be impossible to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't debug the release version of your application with chrome://inspect because debugging in release version is deactivated. You have to use the debug version to debug your app.

Comment: So in the case were a bug is present only in production but not in debug build, there is no way to inspect and find why. I finally found the problem, but it would have been so much easier if I could debug.

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to do debug in production, is possible using this configuration in the config.xml file, for android:

```
<widget ... >
<name>myapp</name>
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application ... android:debuggable="true" />
    </edit-config>
</platform>
```